# Поиск 2-ух переменных

Tags: php, html

Скопировал сайт в переменную и нужно проанализировать его таблицу:

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD'><i>12345</i></td>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD' align='center'>123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD'><i>567</i></td>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD' align='center'>56</td>
</tr>
```

Как в переменные запихнуть 12345, 123, 567, 56 (их длины могут быть разные), помогите, пожалуйста. =)

Comment: А JS не катит ? А то он здесь больще всего подходит, ведь как-никак перед вами стала задача разбора DOM-модели. Ну, а если такой подход все-таки не катит, то XML в самый раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без регулярок тут врядли обойтись, а это не есть гуд. А если вам надо парсить сайт, то [почитайте полезную статейку](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/69149/).

Comment: сложноватая статейка и какая-то не в тему

Answer (score 0):

Ну в php можно воспользоваться такой констукцией.

```
$string = <<<HEX
<tr>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD'><i>12345</i></td>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD' align='center'>123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD'><i>567</i></td>
<td bgcolor='#DDDDDD' align='center'>56</td>
</tr>
HEX;
preg_match_all('#<td(.*)>(.*)</td>#imU', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

---

В string естественно положите свой html код. Т.к. тут html невозможно показать прикладываю картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Глядя на отрывок, можно сказать, что перед нами правильный xml-документ, возможно и поработать с ним можно не через регулярки, а посредством бибилиотек обработки xml документов, например, встроенной SimpleXML.